# javascript debugging gets into VM**** file how to blackbox these files?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, script-debugging

When debugging JS using chrome development tool, while using step into next function(ctrl + ;). I'm getting into file names like VM****.   Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367560/chrome-development-tool-vm-file-from-javascript

Comment: As per above link, this is a duplicate question and should be marked accordingly by someone with that privilege.

Comment: VM is for 'virtual machine.' It means the Javascript engine had to create the code to run it, either inline in an element event handler or through a call to eval().

Comment: can we blackbox/or simply skip this script while debugging, Is there a way for that?

Comment: ended up with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897750/is-it-possible-to-blackbox-all-vm-scripts-in-chrome-debugger

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old subject, but I had the same issue and noticed if I used an Incognito Chrome instance, the VMXXXX scripts no longer show up during the trace when I did an Event Listener Breakpoint (was debugging click). If this helps anyone.